Number of solutions of $f(f(f(x))) = \frac x3$ for $f(x) = 4x(1-x)$ and $x\in[0,1]$
The question says f(x) = 4x(1-x) ∀ x ∈ [0, 1]. It asks the number of distinct solutions of f(f(f(x))) = x/3. I gave it a thought and I solved it as follows and did get the right answer too :
f(x) on analysing becomes 0 for x = 1 and x = 0 and becomes maximum to x = 1/2 (which one can know by differentiating). Now, f(x) ∈ [0, 1] too.
Thus, f(f(x)) will also have domain from [0, 1] and range will also be from [0, 1].
Now, f(f(x)) will become zero for f(x) = 0 or f(x) = 1 [Since f(x) becomes zero for x = 1 and x = 0]. Thus, we get 2 values of x for which f(x) = 0 and 1 value of x for which f(x) = 1. Thus, 3 solutions for f(f(x)) = 0. Now, again f(f(f(x))) will have same domain and range of [0, 1]. For f(f(f(x))) = 0, f(f(x)) = 1 or f(f(x)) = 0 which will have 5 values of x, 3 values for which f(f(x)) = 0 and two values for f(f(x)) = 1. So, f(f(f(x))) = 0 for 5 values of x. Now, after plotting f(f(f(x))), I also plotted line y = x/3, (not to scale and roughly). Now, we known x is from 0 to 1. At x = 0, y = 0 and at x = 1, y = 1/3. Thus, the line will cut it without missing the points that come in its way. On seeing it, we arrive at 8 solutions which is indeed the correct answer too.
I want to ask if someone has an easier or faster approach to solve the problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

thank you for attaching the link

You can ofcourse bruteforce $f(x)$ inside $f(f(f(x)))$

Well that isn't fast way. This looks faster than that to me. This solution looks long while writing but yet it takes much less time then just Substituting. I expect a faster method.

If $f(x)=P(x)$, where $P$ represents a polynomial, then if $P(x)$ has degree $n$, then $f(f(x))$ must have degree $n^2$, $f(f(f(x)))$ must have degree $n^3$ and so on.
Now you have verified yourself that $f(f(f(x)))$ has a range of $[0,1]$, and $x\in[0,1]\implies \frac{x}{3}\in[0,\frac13]$, so
$$f(f(f(x)))=\frac{x}{3}$$
Will have $(2)^3=8$ solutions.(Degree of $4x(1-x)=2$)
This is not an established formula, but a pattern noticed by me. Someone with greater knowledge in this field may help me to present a more compact solution

Will it work for all polynomials?

We don't know about distinct solutions here as per my knowledge?
